# Log4perl: new message in the same line without prefix

Tags: perl, log4perl

Each [Log4perl](http://search.cpan.org/~mschilli/Log-Log4perl/) message starts with a new line:

```
my $log = Log::Log4perl->get_logger("log");
$log->info("start:");
$log->info("10");
$log->info("20");
$log->info("30");
```

result:

```
[2012/07/06 13:12:27] INFO log - start:
[2012/07/06 13:12:27] INFO log - 10
[2012/07/06 13:12:27] INFO log - 20
[2012/07/06 13:12:27] INFO log - 30
```

How can I get next messages on the same line and without prefix:

```
[2012/07/06 13:12:27] INFO log - start: 10 20 30
```

Any ideas?

**UPD:**

I tried to make progress bar for my program. But as a result I need this progress bar only on screen, not at logs.

In this way I did so:

```
$log->info("start");
printf("progress: ");
printf("10");
printf("20");
printf("30");
```

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: $log->info("start: 10 20 30");

Comment: I took a quick look at the Log4perl source. It looks like the `\n` are hardcoded in the `log` method. You could possibly [monkeypatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch) it to not include the `\n`. *Mastering Perl* by brian d foy explains ways to that in chapter 10.

Comment: @simbabque thank you for advice, but it`s overkill for my task

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need a progress bar there is [Term::ProgressBar](http://search.cpan.org/~szabgab/Term-ProgressBar-2.13/lib/Term/ProgressBar.pm) in cpan

Comment: +1 for suggesting the OP pound a nail with a hammer rather than with [an old shoe or a glass bottle](http://weblogs.asp.net/alex_papadimoulis/archive/2005/05/25/408925.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Try using two different categories that both write logs to same place, the screen. Modify their `PatternLayout` and use one or the other when you want to add the date or only the message. You should also add the newline explicity:

Content of `script.pl`:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Log::Log4perl;

my $conf = qq| 
    log4perl.category.Stdout_nl=INFO, Date           
    log4perl.appender.Date=Log::Log4perl::Appender::Screen
    log4perl.appender.Date.layout=PatternLayout
    log4perl.appender.Date.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %p %m

    log4perl.category.Stdout=INFO, Number
    log4perl.appender.Number=Log::Log4perl::Appender::Screen
    log4perl.appender.Number.layout=PatternLayout
    log4perl.appender.Number.layout.ConversionPattern= %-3m
|;

Log::Log4perl::init( \$conf );
my $log_date = Log::Log4perl->get_logger( "Stdout_nl" );
my $log_num = Log::Log4perl->get_logger( "Stdout" );
$log_date->info("start:");
$log_num->info("10");
$log_num->info("20");
$log_num->info("30\n");
```

Run it like:

```
perl script.pl
```

With following output:

```
2012/07/06 12:24:04 INFO start:10 20 30
```